# Max font size for sIFR

Tags: flash, sifr, max, font-size

I am trying to implement a large font for sIFR, but it seems to have a ceiling where you cant go any higher. I have adjusted the the variable MAX_FONT_SIZE within the sIFR.as to no avail. Is this possible or is it a limitation with flash?

Answer (score 0):

It's a Flash limitation.